# ¿Cómo darle formato a tooltip en highcharts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Necesito dar el mismo formato que tiene el `plotOptions` a `tooltip`, anexo imagen real:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi código tengo lo siguiente:

en `inicio_controler.rb`:

```
@datos  = [["Muestra A",   15], ["Muestra B",  22], ["Muestra C", 8]]
```

en la vista:

`index.html.erb`:

*Ya he intentado estas dos versiones y ninguna me muestra el tooltip con el porcentaje:*

**VERSION 1**

```
<% = pie_chart @datos, donut: true, library: {
        title: {
            text: 'Prueba de titulo'
        },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 3,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.y} partidos<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.y} partidos<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }
        }
    } %>
```

**VERSION 2**

```
<% = pie_chart @datos, donut: true, library: {
        title: {
            text: 'Prueba de titulo'
        },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 3,
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>value: {point.y}'
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.y} partidos<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }
        }
    } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar `formatter` en lugar `format` para dar un formato más personalizado; por ejemplo:

```
tooltip: {
  backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderRadius: 10,
  borderWidth: 3,
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br>' + this.y + 'partidos<br>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) + '%';
  },
}
```

Comment: Saludos Estimado gerry, me da este error: 


undefined method `function' for #<#<Class:0x00007f710714bf98>:0x00007f7107b253c0>

Comment: No lo había notado, pero estas utilizando la gema `highcharts-rails`, ¿correcto? No sé cómo podrías utilizar `formatter` con la gema ya que este atributo requiere una función de JavaScript; probablemente encerrando todo en `""` y con `escape_javascript` pueda funcionar. ¿Por qué no utilizas _Highcharts_ sin gema?

Comment: Si me puedes dar algun ejemplo de uso de highchart sin la gema de rails, te lo agradeceria, seria mas directo y me eliminaria el tener que usar una gema, igual estoy investigando como puedo usar el `escape_javascript`